# How to use ctime in Linux

Tags: python, unix

I am getting all the files between 7,30 to 19,30 and 19,30 to 7,30. It was working perfect in Windows but now changed it to run in Linux. It seems to not work now

```
def get_qc_success(ROOT_FOLDER):
    date_start, date_end, shift = get_time()
    
    files = []

    ARCHIVE_FOLDER = os.path.join(ROOT_FOLDER,"qc","A")
     

    for csv in os.listdir(ARCHIVE_FOLDER):
        path = os.path.join(ARCHIVE_FOLDER,csv)
        filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(
                path.stat().st_mtime)
        
        if (date_start < filetime < date_end):
            files.append(csv)
    len_success = len(files)
            
    return files, len_success, shift
```

path.stat().st_mtime is throwing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stat' error

Comment: You assigned `path` to a string in previous line. You probably want to use `os.stat(path)` or `os.path.getmtime(path)`.

Comment: @sardok os.path.getmtime is working ok, but its not working on linux

Comment: well, maybe you should update to the question with the issue you got on linux, what you're expecting, what you're seeing. Not working is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what modules you are using on Windows, but this works for me on Ubuntu:

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat
>>> import datetime
>>> path = '/tmp/foo'
>>> os.stat(path).st_mtime
1607367985.251775
>>> datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.stat(path).st_mtime)
datetime.date(2020, 12, 7)
```